# Global symbol not in symtab

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm getting the following error when trying to output a stack trace through GDB:

> global symbol 'object' found in a.cpp
>   psymtab but not in symtab

What does this error mean exactly, and is it caused by my code or is it a GDB issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's gdb issue. Try gdb 7.0 or 7.1

Comment: Thanks, turns out my older version of GDB was causing the problem.